# not able to make checkchange of checkbox inside datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, datagrid

I have following datagrid having checkbox in first column:

[image]

I am not able to make checkbox selection-unselection when i run the code.

I have following code to have checkbox inside datagrid:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="50" Header="select">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I am new with WPF Project.

Please guid me.

Comment: May be I missed something. If you try to change the value inside your ViewModel, you're missing a binding. Can you clarify this please?

Comment: @Markus  nope i just wanted to have simple checkbox, user will check or uncheck it

Comment: Can't see anything obvious. So here are a few ideas just to start thinking about it. Have you registered some PreviewMouseDown-Events and set them are handled? Have you disabled your entire outer control (grid, tabcontrol etc.)?

Comment: no i have done none of above points...is there any tutorial wich can guid me regarding this?

Comment: Have you started with a dummy-project that just includes the grid and the checkbox-column? Is it possible that you enrich this dummy-project to check when it fails? Tutorial regarding datagrid?! Hm, sorry, havn't found anything suitable